# Get string between multiple couple string, i.e HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Let say I have a string which is extracted from a HTML code.

```
<div>
<foreignobject height="70" width="70" x="152" y="20"><input data-accept="1" /></foreignobject> 
<foreignobject height="70" width="70" x="305" y="20"><input data-accept="2" /></foreignobject>
</div>
```

What I want to do is convert them into things like

```
<div>
<span style="position: absolute; left: 152px; right: 20px"><input data-accept="1" /></span> 
<span style="position: absolute; left: 305px; right: 20px"><input data-accept="2" /></span> 
</div>
```

My strategy is

1. Get all string between `<foreignobject` and `/></foreignobject>`, which I am still struggling now. My idea is using

```
var open = '<foreignobject', close = '/></foreignobject>';
var rege = new RegExp(open +'(.*?)' + close)
var arrBetween = st.split(rege);
```

it show `arrBetween` an array, whose element 1 and 3 is what I need

```
0: "<div> "
1: " height="70" width="70" x="152" y="20"><input data-accept="1" "
2: " "
3: " height="70" width="70" x="305" y="20"><input data-accept="2" "
4: "</div>"
```

How do I do to get `arrBetween` only elements I need, in this case, 2 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using DOMParser to extract the attributes instead?

```js
const input = `<div>
<foreignobject height="70" width="70" x="152" y="20"><input data-accept="1" /></foreignobject> 
<foreignobject height="70" width="70" x="305" y="20"><input data-accept="2" /></foreignobject>
</div>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
doc.body.querySelectorAll('foreignobject').forEach((foreignobject) => {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  const x = foreignobject.getAttribute('x');
  const y = foreignobject.getAttribute('y');
  span.style = `position: absolute; left: ${x}px; right: ${y}px`;
  span.innerHTML = foreignobject.innerHTML;
  foreignobject.replaceWith(span);
});

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

When possible, [best to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) using regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: Is it the most quoted question and answer?